# How do I access projects in SolutionFolders with VS macros?

Tags: vba, visual-studio

I know that I could iterate over the projects of a solution with macros ([more or less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090013/how-could-i-modify-vs-variables-with-a-macro)).

But the top level of my SLN contains of five solution folders. I only obtain these five folders, but not their entries.

I guess that the `Kind` of a `Project` object could tell me whether it's a real project or just a folder. But I cannot find any reference how to find out that.

---

**Edit:**
I know that there's only one solution. With "solution folders" I mean those folders created within a solution using **Solution Explorer → Right Click Solution → Add → New Solution Folder**. This creates a new logical folder that gives you the opportunity to organize the projects of the solution in sub-folders.

Comment: "Solution folders" doesn't mean anything, there's only one solution.

Comment: Yes, I know. See updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you an idea

```
Sub ListSolutionFolders()
        Dim solutionFolder As Project
        Dim solutionFolders As Projects
        Dim name As String
        Dim type As String
        Dim projects As ProjectItems
        Dim project As ProjectItem

        solutionFolders = DTE.Solution.Projects
        For Each solutionFolder In solutionFolders
            name = solutionFolder.Name
            projects = solutionFolder.ProjectItems

            For Each project In projects
                If Not project.SubProject.Kind Is Nothing Then
                    'this is a real project
                    type = project.SubProject.Kind
                Else
                    'Not a project
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Sub
```

Take note of the type, it is a GUID and you look at this link for what it means
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hb23x61k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
Other project types like SSRS is not listed there but outputs a GUID as well

Comment: this is **exactly** the reference that I was looking for! Thank you!